# MySQL join two tables from two columns

Tags: mysql

I'm going to join two table with two columns contain id from another table.

Table users

```
id | first_name | last_name |
---+------------+-----------+
 1 | John       | Doe       |
 2 | Jane       | Doe       |
 3 | Some       | Name      |
```

Table stamp

```
id |    date    | applicant_id  | app_by_id |
---+------------+---------------+-----------+
 1 | 2013-03-15 | 1             | 2         |
 2 | 2013-03-10 | 2             | 3         |
 3 | 2013-03-13 | 2             | 1         |
```

What I want to show:

```
    date    | applicant | app_by    |
------------+-----------+-----------+
 2013-03-15 | John Doe  | Jane Doe  |
 2013-03-10 | Jane Doe  | Some Name |
 2013-03-13 | Jane Doe  | John Doe  |
```

My query:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', NULLIF(t1.first_name, ' '), NULLIF(t1.last_name, ' ')) AS applicant,
    CONCAT_WS(' ', NULLIF(t1.first_name, ' '), NULLIF(t1.last_name, ' ')) AS app_by,
    t2.date
    FROM users t1
    INNER JOIN stamp t2 ON applicant_id = t1.id
```

I know there's something wrong with my query, but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use `LEFT JOIN` so that you get values in each column even if the other join conditions fail. The following code also works with regular `JOIN`.

```
SELECT s.date,
CONCAT_WS(' ', NULLIF(u1.first_name, ' '), NULLIF(u1.last_name, ' ')) AS applicant,
CONCAT_WS(' ', NULLIF(u2.first_name, ' '), NULLIF(u2.last_name, ' ')) AS app_by
FROM stamp s
LEFT JOIN users u1 ON s.applicant_id = u1.id
LEFT JOIN users u2 ON s.app_by_id = u2.id
```

Proof: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/39aff/1/0

Answer (score 0):

Try your joins like

```
SELECT  CONCAT_WS(' ', NULLIF(u1.first_name, ' '), NULLIF(u1.last_name, ' ')) AS applicant,
        CONCAT_WS(' ', NULLIF(u2.first_name, ' '), NULLIF(u2.last_name, ' ')) AS app_by,
        s.date
FROM    stamp s INNER JOIN
        user u1 ON  s.applicant_id = u1.id INNER JOIN
        user u2 ON  s.app_by_id = u1.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of joins, try to use sub query like this.

```
SELECT date, 
(SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', NULLIF(first_name, ' '), NULLIF.last_name, ' ')) from USERS WHERE id = s.applicant_id) as applicant, 
(SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', NULLIF(first_name, ' '), NULLIF.last_name, ' ')) from USERS WHERE id = s.app_by_id) as app_by 
from stamp s
```